# How to query the additional column (other than siblings) added to pivot table?

Tags: swift, postgresql, vapor-fluent

Here is my RecipeIngredientPivot table schema to which I added an addition `quantity` column.

```
-----------------------------------------------------
 id | ingredientID | recipeID | quantity
-----------------------------------------------------
| 1 | A001         | R001       | 100               |
| 2 | A002         | R001       | 50                |
| 3 | C004         | R001       | 23                |
| 4 | A001         | R002       | 75                |
```

I was able to create a `quantity` column to the Pivot table which has the `ingredient_id` and `recipe_id` as siblings by only using Pivot instead of ModifiablePivot.

```
extension RecipeIngredientPivot: Pivot {
    init(_ recipe: Recipe, _ ingredient: Ingredient, _ quantity: Double) throws {
        self.recipeID = try recipe.requireID()
        self.ingredientID = try ingredient.requireID()
        self.quantity = quantity
    }
}
```

However, I am not sure how to query and get quantities of a recipe.

```
extension Recipe {
    var ingredients: Siblings<Recipe, Ingredient, RecipeIngredientPivot> {
        return siblings()
    }

    var quantities: [Double] {
        // Not sure how to get this.
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  I had to do `query(on.req)` & `pivot(on: req)` on the `siblings()` and wait for both to complete successfully before mapping on the results.

```
let ingredientFuture = try recipe.ingredients.query(on: req).all()
let pivotFuture = try recipe.ingredients.pivots(on: req).all()

return ingredientFuture.and(pivotFuture).map { ingredients, pivots in
    for (ingredient,pivot) in zip(ingredients, pivots) {
        print("\(ingredient) - \(pivot.quantity)")
    }
}
```